# Acer OrbiCam in Acer 5102WLMI with Windows 7 Pro won't work?

Tags: laptop, web, camera

My camera seems to open up but shuts down right away without showing any picture.  the message is Windows is checking for solutions but never finds any.  I have tried several different drivers and tried re-installing OrbiCam software several times.

Anyone know ofany drivers or software that might work or have any ideas on how to fix it?

Answer (score 1):

Sorry for my broken english. Look at ACER web site and download Bison driver for the webcam. I have the same problem and with this driver, my webcam is OK